# Can I correlate specific divisor value (float) to specific value (string) on a list?

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement, correlation

I have this specific code which is meant to first convert specific currency into EUR value.
This part of code has been sorted out:

```
country = ['CZ', 'PL']
def f(country, value):
    if "PL" in country.upper():
        value2 = value / 3
    elif "CZ" in country.upper():
        value2 = value / 20
    else:
        raise ValueError
    round(value2, 2)
    print('The conversion of ', value1, input1, 'is: ', value2, 'USD \n')

    if value2 >= 20:
        print('ABOVE Clip level - EU PO is required')
        return ('ABOVE Clip level')
    else:
        print('value {} USD matches expected. BELOW Clip level'.format(value2))
        return ('BELOW clip level')


while True:

    input1 = str(input('Enter Currency [CZK or PLN]: '))
    value1 = float(input('Enter Value: '))

    try:
        f(input1, value1)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Some error occurred, try again.')
```

You will notice that the retrieved value enters a second condition: *if value2 >= 20:*

```
if value2 >= 20:
print('ABOVE Clip level - EU PO is required')
return ('ABOVE Clip level')
else:
    print('value {} USD matches expected. BELOW Clip level'.format(value2))
    return ('BELOW clip level')
```

I would like to achieve a correlation between the country (or currency) and a specific value.
So, let's say if I would like to have:
value2 = 20 as limit for country = PL;
value2 = 10 as limit for country = CZ.

I understood that this should be somehow integrated into the function f but I cannot figure out how.
I have tried to nest it as well as write it separately but it does not return the correct value.
I guess I could create a list of clip level but seems confusing.
The other option was to include a table with correspondence of value per country but honestly, I have no idea if that is possible.
Finally, the last option (the one I am trying right now and still seem not working) is to nest a function cliplimit within the function f:

```
def cliplimit(cliplim):
    for country in f:
        if country == 'PL':
            cliplim = 20
        elif country == 'CZ':
            cliplim = 10
        else:
            raise ValueError
        round(cliplim,0)
        return cliplim

if value2 >= cliplimit():
    print('ABOVE Clip level - EU PO is required')
    return ('ABOVE Clip level')
else:
    print('value {} USD matches expected. BELOW Clip level'.format(value2))
    return ('BELOW clip level')
```

So far the error I get is related to the positional argument cliplim:

```
line 37, in <module>   f(input1, value1) 
line 23, in f
    if value2 >= cliplimit(): TypeError: cliplimit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cliplim'
```

I hope it is not too confusing, but the juice is that I need to assign specific values to specific countries/currencies for clip limit. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments from the first answer and your original code...

Would still need proper error handling

```
#Take in a country and a Value
#Do the conversion based on country
#Determine need for EU PO based on clip level

cliplims = {"PL" : 20, "CZ" : 30}

def convert(country, value):
    if country.upper() == "PL":
        return round(value / 3, 2)
    elif country.upper() == "CZ":
        return round(value / 20, 2)

def above_cliplim(country, value):
    return value >= cliplims[country]

my_country = str(input("Enter Country: "))
my_value = float(input("Enter Value: "))

converted_value = convert(my_country, my_value)
print('The conversion of', my_value, my_country, 'is:', converted_value, 'USD')

if above_cliplim(my_country, converted_value):
    print('ABOVE Clip level - EU PO is required')
else:
    print('value {} BELOW Clip level'.format(converted_value))
```

Comment: Thank you! This code is so far the simplest to understand and I have learned a lot from our conversation. Happy to have had your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the parameter from your cliplimit function? You don't actually use the value passed in for the function.

The error you're getting on line 23 is because you're not passing a value to a function that is expecting one. Since your function doesn't need a value passed in you can remove the parameter and simply define it as `def cliplimit()`

Just to clarify, you do use the cliplim variable in the function, but not the value that's passed in. So you will need to define the variable and possibly set it to a default value.

Also, you have a return statement inside of an iteration so you could remove the loop as well. I don't think you're expecting it to evaluate more than once. I'm thinking you're probably better off passing in the country code to the function and removing the `for country in f`

One more thing... regarding the original f function... You don't want to do your conditional tests against your country list, you want to use the country parameter that's passed in so you'd be better off with conditionals like `if country.upper() == "PL":` - You can probably do without the list all together.

Irregardless of all of the above... if you're just looking to assign a cliplimit value to each country that you can then lookup and use when needed, then consider using a dictionary

```
cliplims = {"PL" : 20, "CZ" : 30} 
print (cliplims["CZ"])
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for the comment. To be honest the idea of a dictionary didn't come at all to my mind. I will try this way and I will see if that will be working. Basically I need to find out if I can call out the dictionary values to state if the value is above or below the clip limit. Such values can be either integer or float. Also thanks for clarifying how to have cleaner code!

Comment: You're welcome. I know how easy it is for code to get messy when you're trying to solve something! To compare against the clip limit, which varies by country, just do something like ```if value2 >= cliplims[country]``` which will use the country passed into f to look up the clip limit and compare it against your value calculation. But... if you're not sure the key (country in this case) will exist in the dictionary you can use ```cliplims.get(country,0)``` which will return the clip limit of that country or return a default value (0 in this example) if the country isn't in the dictionary

Comment: Thank you very much for the further clarification! Unfortunately I keep getting different error according to where I place such line:  'line 15, in f
    if value2 >= cliplims[country]:
KeyError: 'PLN''

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access a key in cliplims that doesn't exist. The ```if value2 >= cliplims[country]``` line is going to look in the dictionary cliplims for a key with the name of whatever the country variable is set to. It will throw an error if the key doesn't exist. Make sure you're using the correct variable (passed in parameter, local, etc) and check the dictionary to see if PLN is a key. It's often easier to see what's going on with your code if you look at one thing and make sure you know what it's doing. Once you have functions, loops, etc the errors can come from many places

Comment: I don't seem to understand, because I thought that it would actually refer to the existing vocabulary and related list:

`country = ["CZ", "PL"] /// 
cliplims = {"CZ": 10, "PL": 20}`. What you are suggesting is to include another one which is the list of currency: `currency = ['CZK','PLN']` and relate that one to countries in order to have a correlation? For example, something like `{"CZ": "CZK": 10, "PL": "PLN":20}` - if that is actually possible

Comment: I wasn't making a distinction between country and currency, is that necessary? The dictionary was just a way to store the cliplimit by country code so you could access it later. You could use other methods if you'd rather. Look at my second answer for what I had in mind. It's a condensed version of the code you included in the question, and does not include any kind of error handling, but it converts the value and determines if it's above the clip limit.